# Hackerrank test question: find sum of max column values from IRIS dataset

Tags: r, testing

[image: hackerrank screenshot]

Hello, so I faced this problem while attempting a recruitment test on hackerrank.

From their question, it is clearly understood that they want the sum of max values of the first four columns of the iris dataset. However, my answer is marked as wrong.

Here is the code:

```html
options(warn = -1)
df <- iris
maxFun <- function(df){
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    for(j in 1:(ncol(df)-1))
    {
          df[i,j]<-as.integer(df[i,j])
    }
}
s<-0
s<-sum(max(df$Sepal.Length),max(df$Sepal.Width),max(df$Petal.Length),max(df$Petal.Width))
return(s)
}
cat(maxFun(df))
```

What is the problem here? and if hackerrank is expecting some other kindmi of output, why are the questions not clear enough?

Comment: Didn't check your code fully but you can do `sum(sapply(Filter(is.numeric, iris), max))`

Comment: it is attached as a picture above, copying it was not allowed

Comment: Your mistake is using `as.integer` instead of `as.numeric`. Your code returns 19, not 21.7.

Comment: The correct solution, among many, would be: `sum(sapply(lapply(iris[,1:4], FUN=as.numeric), FUN=max))` The inner lapply converts the first 4 columns to numeric. The outer sapply finds the maximum value of each column, returning a nice vector suitable for the `sum` function.

Comment: Thankyou!! as.numeric solved the problem!

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to convert individual cells in the dataframe to numeric values and then save them at the same place, instead of a new dataframe . **This will not convert the class of that column**. You can us `print(df`) after the loop and check this. So when you try to find the max value, the values are   still  character , and there will be an error .

Now, you might not encounter an error if you try it on your system because Iris dataframe  actually  has numeric columns . To simulate above structure, you first have to convert the columns to character.  You can change the class of all columns with :

```
df<- apply(X=iris, MARGIN = 2, FUN = as.character)
```

The second thing is that in R you would avoid the use of loops. You can use the same `apply` method to find columwise or rowwise sums

Comment: For column-wise operations on dataframe use `lapply`, `sapply` or `vapply`. `apply` will coerce the dataframe to a matrix with unintended side effects maybe.

Comment: Thankyou!!I did not know about the apply functions.

Comment: And I had totally overlooked `as.numeric` pointed by Edward above, which will indeed lead to a wrong answer.

Comment: Edit: `as.integer`